# Measure path of multiple objects in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape

Firstly, I'm a total novice, so please excuse me if this is a basic question.

I'm designing a backboard for a neon flex sign which will contain text and a surrounding circle. I'm trying to calculate how much of the neon Flex I'll need to order to fit my design/tweak the size of my design to ensure it works with the dimensions of the flex neon LED strip.

There's two things I need to consider
1) I need the width of the text to be about 7mm so when its etched via laser cutter or CNC router I can set the Neon Flex rope into the groove. 
2) I need to know what length of Neon Flex rope to order once the design is complete.

So far I've been eyeballing the width by using a monoline font and measuring the width after setting a font size. Is there an easier way?

Im using Measure path extension to determine the length of each path, but wondering is there a simple way to combine them all so I get a single answer. presently, if I select multiple letters in the text after switching Object to path, i get a result above each letter separately. This might be handy when it comes to cutting, but for now I just need to know the combined total length of the whole design. Can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can combine separate paths using *Path > Combine*. It seems to work with the Measure Path extension, with a tiny rounding error.

Example

[image]

You can set a stroke width in millimetres in the Fill & Stroke panel.

Example

[image]